# Efficient way to get all simple products from large list of configurables?

Tags: magento-enterprise

I have categories which contain a very large number of configurable products, and I need to load data from each of those products' child (simple) products on the category page (`catalog/product/list.phtml`).

The problem is, **only the configurable products are merchandised into the category**. The simple child products are not assigned to any category, so the following code doesn't work:

```
// Only loads the configurables
$products = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)
           ->getProductCollection()
           ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

My current method, therefore, is to loop through each configurable and load its child products using code like this:

```
foreach ($configurableProducts as $configurable) {
    $childProducts[] = $configurable->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProducts(null, $configurable);
}
```

However, this is horribly slow.

Is there a method whereby I can quickly load the simple products, given a large list of configurables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have optimized query.Instead of using of get all simple products object from configurable products object.

```
foreach ($configurableProducts as $configurable) {
 $childProducts[] = 
$configurable->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProducts(null, $configurable);
 }
```

**Trying get all simple product ids  and create a simple product collection and filter then configurable child  simple products**

```
$Table=$configurableProducts->getTable('catalog/product_super_link');
$parentIds=$configurableProducts->getAllIds(); 
$ReadAdapter = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');

         $select = $ReadAdapter->select()
            ->from(array('l' => $Table), array('product_id'))
            ->join(
                array('e' => $configurableProducts->getTable('catalog/product')),
                'e.entity_id = l.product_id AND e.required_options = 0',
                array()
            )
            ->where('parent_id IN(?) ', $parentIds)
            ->group('l.product_id')
            ;
```

**The above query give the simple product ids on basic of configurable Products  simple products ids  collection then

filter then below collection**

```
$collectionTwo = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('type_id','simple');
$collectionTwo->addIdFilter(array(new Zend_Db_Expr("{$select}")));
```

Comment: Thank you, this does work. `$collectionTwo` is a collection of all simple products in the category. However, can I also store each simple product's `parent_id` as part of the collection data, so that I can associate each simple product with its correct parent?